# How to fetch data on basis of last update date from multiple joined tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which pulls full data dump from different tables using joins on basis that some tables can be blank.
Now the requirement is to fetch data when ever there is some update in any of the columns which are getting selected.

Below is the query which pulls full data dump

```
    select 
papf.person_number,
ppnf.display_name,
(select to_char(psdf.seniority_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
from
per_seniority_dates_f psdf
where
paam.person_id = psdf.person_id and
psdf.seniority_date_code = 'MJ_ENT_SEN_DATE'
and trunc(sysdate) between psdf.effective_start_date and psdf.effective_end_date
) as "Enterprise Joining Date",
to_char(paam.retirement_date,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Retirement date",
--to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Resignation Date",
(
select max(to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'))
from 
hrc_txn_header hth, 
HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd,
per_all_assignments_m paam_int 
where 
paam.person_id=paam_int.person_id
and paam_int.person_id=hth.subject_id 
and paam_int.assignment_id=hth.object_id
and hrcd.transaction_id=hth.transaction_id
and hth.module_identifier IN ('Resignation','Terminations')
group by paam_int.person_id)as "Resignation_Date",

to_char(ppos.actual_termination_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Seperation Date",
to_char(pp.date_of_birth, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Date of Birth",
pg.name as Grade,
pea.email_address as "Email Id",
ppnf.legislation_code as "Country Code",
(case when ppnf.legislation_code in ('IN') then 'India'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('US') then 'United States of America'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('GB') then 'Great Britain'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('MY') then 'Malaysia'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('SG') then 'Singapore'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('IE') then 'Ireland'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('CA') then 'Canada'
else '' end)
as "Country",
hla.Location_name as "location name",
hle1.name as "Legal Entity Name",
fabu.bu_name as "Employee Unit Name",
hou.name as "Department",
(case when pplf.sex IN ('M') then 'Male'
when pplf.sex IN ('F') then 'Female' 
else ' ' end) as Gender,
(case when to_char(ppos.actual_termination_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')=to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then 'INACTIVE'
else 'ACTIVE' end) as "IsActive",
pj.name as "Designation",
to_char(paam.date_probation_end,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Confirmation Date",
(
select to_char(paam_trf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
from 
per_all_Assignments_m paam_trf
where 
trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam_trf.effective_Start_date) and trunc(paam_trf.effective_end_date)
and papf.person_id=paam_trf.person_id
and paam_trf.ACTION_CODE IN ('GLB_TRANSFER')
and paam_trf.assignment_status_TYPE='ACTIVE'
and paam_trf.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
)as "Repatriation_Date",

(case when paam.assignment_type in ('E') then 'Employee'
when paam.assignment_type in ('C') then 'Contingent Worker'
else '' end) as "Employee_Group",
flv1.MEANING "Job Function/Class",
pjft.job_family_name as "Job Family",
pjf.attribute1 as "Career Stream",
paam.ass_attribute1 as "Job Descriptor 1",
paam.ass_attribute2 as "Job Descriptor 2",
pj.name as "Title",
papf1.person_number as "Line_Manager ID",
(ppnf1.first_name ||' '|| ppnf1.last_name) as "Line_Manager",
(select pp.phone_number from
per_phones pp
--where papf.primary_phone_id = pp.phone_id(+)
where papf.person_id = pp.person_id
and trunc(sysdate) between pp.date_from and NVL(pp.date_to, sysdate + 1)
and pp.phone_type IN ('HM')
and rownum = 1
) 
as Mobile_Number,

(select pp.phone_number from
per_phones pp
where papf.person_id = pp.person_id
and trunc(sysdate) between pp.date_from and NVL(pp.date_to, sysdate + 1)
and pp.phone_type IN ('W1') 
and rownum = 1)
as Extension,
pu.username as "Windows Login"


from
per_all_people_f papf,
per_person_names_f ppnf,
per_all_assignments_m paam,
per_periods_of_service ppos,
per_persons pp,
per_grades pg,
per_email_addresses pea,
hr_legal_entities hle1,
hr_organization_units hou,
fun_all_business_units_v fabu,
hr_locations_all hla,
per_people_legislative_f pplf,
per_jobs pj,
FND_LOOKUP_VALUES flv1,
PER_JOB_FAMILY_F_TL pjft,
per_jobs_F pjf,
per_all_people_f papf1,
per_person_names_f ppnf1,
per_assignment_supervisors_f pasf,
per_users pu



where
trunc(sysdate) between trunc(ppnf.effective_start_date) and trunc(ppnf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam.effective_start_date) and trunc(paam.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(papf.effective_start_date) and trunc(papf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(hle1.effective_start_date) and trunc(hle1.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(pg.effective_start_date) and trunc(pg.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between nvl(pea.date_from,to_date('01-01-1951','DD-MM-YYYY')) and nvl(pea.date_to,to_date('31-12-4712','DD-MM-YYYY'))
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(pplf.effective_start_date) and trunc(pplf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between pjft.effective_start_date(+) and pjft.effective_end_date(+)
and trunc(sysdate) between ppnf1.effective_start_date(+) and ppnf1.effective_end_date(+)
and trunc(sysdate) between pasf.effective_start_date(+) and pasf.effective_end_date(+)



and papf.person_id=ppnf.person_id
and papf.person_id=paam.person_id
--and papf.person_id=paaf.person_id
and papf.person_id=pp.person_id
and paam.period_of_service_id= ppos.period_of_service_id
and paam.location_id = hla.location_id
and paam.legal_entity_id=hle1.organization_id
and paam.business_unit_id=fabu.bu_id
and paam.organization_id = hou.organization_id
and paam.grade_id=pg.grade_id
and papf.person_id = pea.person_id(+)
and pea.email_type(+) in ('W1')
and papf.person_id = pplf.person_id(+)
and paam.legislation_code=pplf.legislation_code
and paam.job_id = pj.job_id
and flv1.LOOKUP_CODE(+) = pj.job_function_code
and flv1.lookup_type(+) = 'JOB_FUNCTION_CODE'
and pj.job_family_id=pjft.job_family_id
and pj.job_id=pjf.job_id
and paam.assignment_id = pasf.assignment_id(+)
and pasf.manager_id = papf1.person_id(+)
and pasf.manager_id = ppnf1.person_id(+)
and papf.person_id=pu.person_id(+)
and paam.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
and paam.assignment_status_type in ('ACTIVE')
and hle1.status in ('A')
and hle1.CLASSIFICATION_CODE in ('HCM_LEMP')
and ppnf.name_type(+) IN ('GLOBAL') 
and ppnf1.name_type(+) IN ('GLOBAL') 
and fabu.status='A'
and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
and paam.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE ='Y'
```

and below is the query in which I am trying to pull data on basis of last update date of assignment table, now need to add last update date for other columns as well. The output logic should be like whenever there is change in any of the columns that particular row for the person should come in extract

```
    select 
papf.person_number,
ppnf.display_name,
(select to_char(psdf.seniority_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
from
per_seniority_dates_f psdf
where
paam.person_id = psdf.person_id and
psdf.seniority_date_code = 'MJ_ENT_SEN_DATE'
and trunc(sysdate) between psdf.effective_start_date and psdf.effective_end_date
) as "Enterprise Joining Date",
to_char(paam.retirement_date,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Retirement date",
--to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Resignation Date",
(
select max(to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'))
from 
hrc_txn_header hth, 
HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd,
per_all_assignments_m paam_int 
where 
paam.person_id=paam_int.person_id
and paam_int.person_id=hth.subject_id 
and paam_int.assignment_id=hth.object_id
and hrcd.transaction_id=hth.transaction_id
and hth.module_identifier IN ('Resignation','Terminations')
group by paam_int.person_id)as "Resignation_Date",

to_char(ppos.actual_termination_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Seperation Date",
to_char(pp.date_of_birth, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Date of Birth",
pg.name as Grade,
pea.email_address as "Email Id",
ppnf.legislation_code as "Country Code",
(case when ppnf.legislation_code in ('IN') then 'India'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('US') then 'United States of America'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('GB') then 'Great Britain'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('MY') then 'Malaysia'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('SG') then 'Singapore'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('IE') then 'Ireland'
when ppnf.legislation_code in ('CA') then 'Canada'
else '' end)
as "Country",
hla.Location_name as "location name",
hle1.name as "Legal Entity Name",
fabu.bu_name as "Employee Unit Name",
hou.name as "Department",
(case when pplf.sex IN ('M') then 'Male'
when pplf.sex IN ('F') then 'Female' 
else ' ' end) as Gender,
(case when to_char(ppos.actual_termination_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')=to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') then 'INACTIVE'
else 'ACTIVE' end) as "IsActive",
pj.name as "Designation",
to_char(paam.date_probation_end,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Confirmation Date",
(
select to_char(paam_trf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
from 
per_all_Assignments_m paam_trf
where 
trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam_trf.effective_Start_date) and trunc(paam_trf.effective_end_date)
and papf.person_id=paam_trf.person_id
and paam_trf.ACTION_CODE IN ('GLB_TRANSFER')
and paam_trf.assignment_status_TYPE='ACTIVE'
and paam_trf.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
)as "Repatriation_Date",

(case when paam.assignment_type in ('E') then 'Employee'
when paam.assignment_type in ('C') then 'Contingent Worker'
else '' end) as "Employee_Group",
flv1.MEANING "Job Function/Class",
pjft.job_family_name as "Job Family",
pjf.attribute1 as "Career Stream",
paam.ass_attribute1 as "Job Descriptor 1",
paam.ass_attribute2 as "Job Descriptor 2",
pj.name as "Title",
papf1.person_number as "Line_Manager ID",
(ppnf1.first_name ||' '|| ppnf1.last_name) as "Line_Manager",
(select pp.phone_number from
per_phones pp
--where papf.primary_phone_id = pp.phone_id(+)
where papf.person_id = pp.person_id
and trunc(sysdate) between pp.date_from and NVL(pp.date_to, sysdate + 1)
and pp.phone_type IN ('HM')
and rownum = 1
) 
as Mobile_Number,

(select pp.phone_number from
per_phones pp
where papf.person_id = pp.person_id
and trunc(sysdate) between pp.date_from and NVL(pp.date_to, sysdate + 1)
and pp.phone_type IN ('W1') 
and rownum = 1)
as Extension,
pu.username as "Windows Login"


from
per_all_people_f papf,
per_person_names_f ppnf,
per_all_assignments_m paam,
per_periods_of_service ppos,
per_persons pp,
per_grades pg,
per_email_addresses pea,
hr_legal_entities hle1,
hr_organization_units hou,
fun_all_business_units_v fabu,
hr_locations_all hla,
per_people_legislative_f pplf,
per_jobs pj,
FND_LOOKUP_VALUES flv1,
PER_JOB_FAMILY_F_TL pjft,
per_jobs_F pjf,
per_all_people_f papf1,
per_person_names_f ppnf1,
per_assignment_supervisors_f pasf,
per_users pu



where
trunc(sysdate) between trunc(ppnf.effective_start_date) and trunc(ppnf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam.effective_start_date) and trunc(paam.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(papf.effective_start_date) and trunc(papf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(hle1.effective_start_date) and trunc(hle1.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(pg.effective_start_date) and trunc(pg.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between nvl(pea.date_from,to_date('01-01-1951','DD-MM-YYYY')) and nvl(pea.date_to,to_date('31-12-4712','DD-MM-YYYY'))
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(pplf.effective_start_date) and trunc(pplf.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between pjft.effective_start_date(+) and pjft.effective_end_date(+)
and trunc(sysdate) between ppnf1.effective_start_date(+) and ppnf1.effective_end_date(+)
and trunc(sysdate) between pasf.effective_start_date(+) and pasf.effective_end_date(+)

--AND (paam.last_update_date + interval '0 05:30:00' day TO second ) BETWEEN To_date(:p_time1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND To_date(:p_time2, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
AND to_char(paam.last_update_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2020-03-01'  AND '2020-03-07'
--AND (ppnf.last_update_date + interval '0 05:30:00' day TO second ) BETWEEN To_date(:p_time1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND To_date(:p_time2, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
OR to_char(ppnf.last_update_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2020-03-01'  AND '2020-03-07'


and papf.person_id=ppnf.person_id
and papf.person_id=paam.person_id
--and papf.person_id=paaf.person_id
and papf.person_id=pp.person_id
and paam.period_of_service_id= ppos.period_of_service_id
and paam.location_id = hla.location_id
and paam.legal_entity_id=hle1.organization_id
and paam.business_unit_id=fabu.bu_id
and paam.organization_id = hou.organization_id
and paam.grade_id=pg.grade_id
and papf.person_id = pea.person_id(+)
and pea.email_type(+) in ('W1')
and papf.person_id = pplf.person_id(+)
and paam.legislation_code=pplf.legislation_code
and paam.job_id = pj.job_id
and flv1.LOOKUP_CODE(+) = pj.job_function_code
and flv1.lookup_type(+) = 'JOB_FUNCTION_CODE'
and pj.job_family_id=pjft.job_family_id
and pj.job_id=pjf.job_id
and paam.assignment_id = pasf.assignment_id(+)
and pasf.manager_id = papf1.person_id(+)
and pasf.manager_id = ppnf1.person_id(+)
and papf.person_id=pu.person_id(+)
and paam.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
and paam.assignment_status_type in ('ACTIVE')
and hle1.status in ('A')
and hle1.CLASSIFICATION_CODE in ('HCM_LEMP')
and ppnf.name_type(+) IN ('GLOBAL') 
and ppnf1.name_type(+) IN ('GLOBAL') 
and fabu.status='A'
and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
and paam.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE ='Y'
```

I know I might be completely wrong here, but any help would be great.

Thanks
Shivam

Comment: Help me write query for extracting data whenever there is change in any of the select columns. The second Query I added last update one paam table but also need to do for other select columns. If I write the last update date condition in where clause then it will pull on basis of AND condition. whereas I want to pull data if any of the column has change

Comment: Put the OR tests in a bracketed set. (`and (paam.last_update_date between ... or papf.last_update_date between ... or ...)` etc). Your bigger challenge will be removing those hardcoded dates. Why don't you just build a materialized view for your core query and let mview logs handle the changes?